# Cloudformation exports cannot be deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to delete a stack on Cloudformation but it return a rollback `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`.
I have removed all dependencies from the template and all the outputs as well but the error persists.

Is there a way to force a delete? or even better just to delete the outpus?

I removed the outputs from the template and ran `update-stack` but without success. The error persist.

Comment: you can find which stacks are using given export from cloudformation console exports tab ex: [For us-east-1](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/exports) and delete all those stacks!

Comment: Yes, you can list the exports with `aws cloudformation list-exports`nut the problem is, it doesn't allow me to delete the stack where the exports lives.

Comment: I think there is a dependency or a link between the stack and the exports. I can't delete the stack and I can't remove the exports without removing the stack.

Comment: "I think there is a dependency or a link between the stack and the exports. I can't delete the stack and I can't remove the exports without removing the stack." - You cannot delete or modify exports/outputs which are imported by other stacks. This includes deleting the stack which is exporting those outputs. You need to find the stack that is *importing* those values, and stop it from doing do - whether that is deleting the importing stack, or changing it to not import the value(s).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. How do you find which stack is importing those values? I just have one stack, the one that I want to delete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you created a circular reference issue? I’ve run into this in the past, even referencing an export from the current stack in that stack (easy to do when you make updates). The solution is to modify the stacks that are referencing The export, and removing the resource(s) that has the reference. Update the stack with the reference(s) removed and then you can do the delete. If you no longer have the start template you can modify it in the console by editing the existing stack, or you can copy the template from the console and edit it elsewhere. Any way you go about it, the key is updating the stack(s) with `ImportValue` references removed, then deleting the stack(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakenly created a circular reference to two stacks using aws cdk. I could not delete or modify either stack via cdk, aws cli or the cloudformation console, designer or by uploading a new template.

What did work was clicking on the stack in the cloudformation console, then clicking "Stack Actions" in the top right and then clicking "View in Application Manager". In that dashboard all my stacks were listed and there was an option to delete the stacks there. Deleting the problematic stacks there worked.